# how to update parent field using trigger

Tags: apex, soql

i have two object incident and task (both are custom) related with lookup.task is a child object.i have to mark rapid_request__c field of incident checked when task_type__c is 'rapid delivery'.I have written trigger.but it's not working.here is my trigger.

```
trigger CHS_Update_rapid_request on BMCServiceDesk__Task__c (After update,After insert) 
 {
     Set<id>taskId=new Set<id>();
     Map<Id,BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c>incidentMP;
     for(BMCServiceDesk__Task__c tskobj:trigger.new)
     {
             taskId.add(tskobj.BMCServiceDesk__FKIncident__c);
     }
       incidentMP=new Map<Id,BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c>([select Id,Rapid_Request__c,(select Task_Type__c from BMCServiceDesk__Tasks__r)from BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c where id in:taskId]);
       for(BMCServiceDesk__Task__c tsk:trigger.new)
        {
               if(tsk.Task_Type__c=='Rapid Delivery')
               {
                    BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c inciobj=incidentMP.get(tsk.BMCServiceDesk__FKIncident__c);
                    inciobj.Rapid_Request__c=true;
               }

        }
        update incidentMP.values();
}
```

Comment: In my opinion, in this case(simple update of parent field) would be better to use workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply update the parent record using the Id like below.

this way you don't have to query again and 2 for loops

```
trigger CHS_Update_rapid_request on BMCServiceDesk__Task__c (After update,After insert) 
{
     List<BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c> lstBMCServiceDeskIncidentToUpdate = new List<BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c>();
     Map<Id,BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c>incidentMP;
     for(BMCServiceDesk__Task__c tskobj:trigger.new)
     {
        if(tskobj.Task_Type__c=='Rapid Delivery')
        {
            lstBMCServiceDeskIncidentToUpdate.add(new BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c(Id = tskobj.BMCServiceDesk__FKIncident__c,
                                                    Rapid_Request__c=true));
        }
     }
     update lstBMCServiceDeskIncidentToUpdate;

}
```

Comment: Hi Ratan, thanks for your reply.i tried your code but still the check box is not getting checked if task type is rapid delevery.

Comment: ohhh i am sorryyy it is working thanks a lot ratan

Comment: @Abhisheksingh cool. if this issue resolved then dont forget to mark the best answer.